# Jprobe Profiling java application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jprobe

Im using jprobe to profile my java application.The java application that Im trying to profile is an eclipse based application. we have created multiple projects for the application to deliver various features. When we build the application, the application is exported as a product and we receive a .exe file. I would like to know how to profile a .exe file using jprobe. Since from the help documents, I could see that the jar file will be used for profiling the application. But in our case the application is an exe file.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So where should be the problem? I don’t know much about `jprobe` but as all free profiling tools are able to connect to a running Java application regardless of whether started via jar or exe I would not pay any cent for a tool if it is not able to do so.

With other tools it works by just starting the tool and your application and clicking on an entry in the list of running applications. You may try it with jvisualvm which is shipped with the JDK. In case jprobe has no such feature (I can’t imagine that) you could use jvisualvm to store heap dumps, etc. and load them into jprobe.

Or just use the command line tool. `jps` gives you a list of running Java applications including a *pid* and, e.g. `jmap -dump:file=bla.hprof *pid*` creates a heap dump.

The bottom line is, there are plenty of tools having no problem analyzing a Java application started via exe file so I don’t see any reason why jprobe should have problems with it.